# Touchpad/Trackpoint is overreacting

Tags: 12.10, mouse, thinkpad

since I've installed Ubuntu I have problems with my touchpad. 
First under GNOME/Unity my touchpad was freezing for a couple of seconds with this dmesg-error:

```
psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
```

(only with the touchpad/trackpoint but not with my USB-Mouse)
Then some months later I changed from unity desktop to xfce-desktop & then to KDE:
my touchpad AND trackpoint are either freezing for  or are 'overreacting' (whole time till restart): When I touch the touchpad(AND trackpoint) it clicks everything with a right or leftclick and the cursor goes 'crazy'.
dmesg:

```
psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request
psmouse serio1: synaptics: device claims to have extended capabilities, but I'm not able to read them.
psmouse serio1: synaptics: device claims to have extended capability 0x0c, but I'm not able to read it.
psmouse serio1: synaptics: hardware appears to be different: id(149271-149271), model(114865-114865), caps(d047b3-d047b1), ext(b40000-0).
psmouse serio1: bad data from KBC - timeout
```

I cannot solve this problem with restarting xserver (login-logut), I must restart ubuntu to get the touchpad working.

But here my Xorg Log

```
[    37.683] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    37.683] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    37.683] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.684] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    37.684] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: ignoring touch events for semi-multitouch device
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1472 - 5888
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1408 - 4820
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right double triple
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[    37.684] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    37.684] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    37.684] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: AccelFactor is now 0.036
[    37.684] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[  8465.562] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0xb6326000+0xcf65) [0xb6332f65]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0xb6326000+0x6c75) [0xb632cc75]
[  8625.425] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
```

I'm using a Thinkpad L420 with Ubutnu 12.10. (New Kernel/all up to date.)
I have tested a lot of things like set with gpointing-device-settings the lowest acceleration but I won't work for me.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My Fix:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_mousereset
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_mousereset
```

paste/type in the following and save:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
        hibernate)
                ;;
        suspend)
                ;;
        thaw|resume)
                sleep 2
                /sbin/rmmod psmouse
                sleep 2
                /sbin/modprobe psmouse
                ;;
        *)      echo "ERROR calling " $0
                ;;
esac

sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/00_mousereset
```

Save and next time you suspend/resume it should work.

Comment: Consider explaining why you think your answer will work. That will make people have more confidence in trying your suggestion.